# Introduce a number of students from keyboard and theirs marks

Tags: c

I need to introduce a no. of students , theirs name, surname and marks(3 marks). The average of the marks must be made, and then those who have passed must be displayed in the reverse order of their insertion.The problem is that, for example, i have 3 students i need to introduce 4 times in the structure to show me the result, and i need to have one after another, not with spaces or something else. Someone who can help me? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 struct students
    {
        char name[100];
        char surname[100];
        float a,b,c;
    };
int main()
{
int n,i,j;
scanf("%d",&n);
struct students s[n];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
       scanf("\n%s %s %f %f %f\n",s[i].name,s[i].surname,&s[i].a,&s[i].b,&s[i].c);

    }
    for(j=n;j>=1;j--)
    {
    float m;
    m=(s[j].a+s[j].b+s[j].c)/3;
    if(s[j].a >= 5 && s[j].b >= 5 && s[j].c >= 5 && m >= 6)
       {
       printf("%s %s %.2f\n", s[j].name, s[j].surname, m);
       }
     }
 return 0;
 }
```

[image: Example of desired output]

Comment: Why did you tag c#?

Comment: Array indexing begins at `0` not `1`. That's why an extra array element is needed. `struct students s[3];` can be indexed by 0, 1, or 2 , but your code is indexing by 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [tour], and browse the [Help] to get an insight of how the site works. Please do not post *images of text*. It is far easier to read (and to post!) if you just copy that output into your question and format it as `code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have an array of structures and you are indexing them wrongly.

Given you have n = 3, then you have an array of 3 structures indexed 0, 1 and 2.

First you need to change your structure reading for loop to this

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    scanf("\n%s %s %f %f %f\n",s[i].name,s[i].surname,&s[i].a,&s[i].b,&s[i].c); }
```

For your next for loop, you need to change it to this

```
for(j=n - 1;j>=0;j--)
```

Hope this helps